# How to launch an instance with multiple SGs selected from a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to launch an instance and add more than one security groups. I am using AWS params.

```
    "SecurityGroupID": {
        "Description": "Select one Security Group ID (Must be available to the VPC)",
        "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>"
    },
```

Using !Ref (see below) I am getting an error: Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String

```
    "Ec2Instance" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties" : {
            "SecurityGroupIds" : [{"Ref": "SecurityGroupID"}],
        }
    }
```

Its working with Select but returns only the first SG from the list. I would like to get the full list of SGs in SecurityGroupIds.

"SecurityGroupIds" : [{"Fn::Select": [ "0", {"Ref": "SecurityGroupID"}]}],

Thanks

Comment: Your title is about security groups, but the code that you pasted is about subnets, and has no context (I assume that it's a parameter definition). If you want a good answer, you should edit your question to show the actual parameter definition _and_ the resource definition that uses it. Also, whenever you get an error, include the _exact_ error in the question.

Comment: Good point kdgregory. I have updated my question.

Comment: Did you try: "SecurityGroupIds" : {"Ref": "SecurityGroupID"}

Comment: Yes, its giving the error: Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String

Comment: I'm saying use {"Ref": "SecurityGroupID"} rather  than [{"Ref": "SecurityGroupID"}]

Answer (score 1):

You specify that the `SecurityGroupID` parameter is a list, but then you reference that parameter inside a list construct. So what you're doing is trying to assign a list-of-lists to an attribute that only accepts a list.

Change your `Properties` attribute to look like this (as @jarmod said in comments):

```
"Properties" : {
    "SecurityGroupIds" : {"Ref": "SecurityGroupID"},
}
```

It would also be less confusing if you named the parameter `SecurityGroupIDs`, to make it obvious that it's a list.